# 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 with cmake

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile a test class using cmake on mac. When I run the cmake and make commands, I end up with this error:

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
    CMakeFiles/Carm.dir/CMakeFiles/3.7.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Carm.dir/test.cpp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [Carm] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Carm.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Telling me that there is a duplicate symbol in main. This code compiles perfectly when I do it with g++ alone.

car.h

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace test {
    class Car {
    private:
            string model;
            int hp;
            int speed;

    public:
            Car(string n_model, int n_hp);
            string getModel();
            int getHp();
            int getSpeed();

    };
}
#endif
```

car.cpp

```
#include "car.h"

using namespace test;

Car::Car(string n_model, int n_hp) {
        model = n_model;
        hp = n_hp;
        speed = 0;
}

string Car::getModel() {
        return model;
}

int Car::getHp() {
        return hp;
}

int Car::getSpeed() {
        return speed;
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include "car.h"
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;
using namespace test;

int main() {
        Car car1("BMW", 400);
        Car car2("Hellcat", 707);

        printf("hp-%d speed-%d\n", car1.getHp(), car1.getSpeed());
        printf("hp-%d speed-%d\n", car2.getHp(), car2.getSpeed());

        return 0;
}
```

And this is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Carm)

file(GLOB_RECURSE Carm_SOURCES "*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE Carm_HEADERS "*.h")

set(Carm_INCLUDE_DIRS "")
foreach(_headerFile ${Carm_HEADERS})
        get_filename_component(_dir ${_headerFile} PATH)
        list(APPEND Carm_INCLUDE_DIRS ${_dir})
endforeach()
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES Carm_INCLUDE_DIRS)

include_directories(${Carm_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(Carm ${Carm_SOURCES})
```

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. test.cpp is my main. There is no main.cpp. Just poor labeling on my end.

Comment: You don't need to have a file called `main.cpp`. Just one of the files needs to contain `main()` if you're writing an executable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your executable you have two main functions (print out `Carm_SOURCES` by `MESSAGE(${Carm_SOURCES}))`. One is in `test.cpp` and one in `CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp` (which is a file that CMake generates to test if your CXX compiler works correctly). The `GLOB_RECURSE` finds and adds both of these files to `Carm_SOURCES`

It is not recommended to use `GLOB` to collect a list of source files. From the file(GLOB documentation:

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your 
>   source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed 
>   then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

The recommended way to list project files is to add them by hand to `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue.